# How to filter records based on another grouped by column in a same table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a sample table as below:

[image]

Target output:

[image]

I have tried with below script but only number of count produced as output:

```
select ID, count(COUNTRY) from test
group by COUNTRY
having count(COUNTRY)=3;
```

Could anyone here please help how can I get the targeted output? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one option - a subquery:

Sample data:

```
SQL> with test (id, name, country) as
  2    (select 1, 'Mike' , 'Australia' from dual union all
  3     select 2, 'Jason', 'Australia' from dual union all
  4     select 3, 'Lee'  , 'China'     from dual union all
  5     select 4, 'Simon', 'India'     from dual union all
  6     select 5, 'Alex' , 'Malaysia'  from dual union all
  7     select 6, 'John' , 'Australia' from dual
  8    )
```

Query:

```
  9  select id, country
 10  from test
 11  where country in (select country
 12                    from test
 13                    group by country
 14                    having count(*) = 3
 15                   )
 16  order by id;

        ID COUNTRY
---------- ---------
         1 Australia
         2 Australia
         6 Australia

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use analytic functions and only scan the table once:

```sql
SELECT id, name, country
FROM   (
  SELECT id, name, country,
         COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY country) AS people_per_country
  FROM   table_name
)
WHERE  people_per_country = 3;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (id, name, country) AS
  SELECT 1, 'Mike' , 'Australia' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'Jason', 'Australia' FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
  SELECT 3, 'Lee'  , 'China'     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 'Simon', 'India'     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, 'Alex' , 'Malaysia'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 6, 'John' , 'Australia' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | ID | NAME | COUNTRY |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | Mike | Australia |
> | 2 | Jason | Australia |
> | 6 | John | Australia |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=fad0b6b5c32704c7ab48a35cee3756fd)*